# How to detect column that starts with special characters

Tags: sql

I have a table with records like

- dog
- cat
- mouse
- :mouse
- ????cat

I'm trying select all values from the table but if the value starts with a special character then ignore it. In total, the list equates to 5 recors but should only return 3 since the last 2 starts with special characters.

What would be the best way to achieve this in my select statement?

Comment: If it's only 2, then something like this might work : `WHERE t.ingredient NOT LIKE '[:?]%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

- MySQL: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]'`
- PostgreSQL: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col ~ '^[a-zA-Z]'`
- Oracle: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col, '^[a-zA-Z]')`